# What does < do in Perl in this instance?

Tags: perl, syntax, cgi

I am confused as to what the second line does in this snippet of code.  $runas should be evaluated to the user's uid i think.  What does the $< do?  This is contained in a CGI script.

```
my $runAS = (getpwnam("username"))[2];
$runAS = $< if ($runAS == 0);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$<` is a [special variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) in perl:

> The real uid of this process. You can change both the real uid and the
>   effective uid at the same time by using POSIX::setuid() . Since
>   changes to $< require a system call, check $! after a change attempt
>   to detect any possible errors.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple.

Comment: I see that you cite the reference as well, it was just hidden in a hyperlink.

Answer (score 6):

from http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

```
$<
```

The real uid of this process. You can change both the real uid and the effective uid at the same time by using POSIX::setuid() . Since changes to $< require a system call, check $! after a change attempt to detect any possible errors.

Mnemonic: it's the uid you came from, if you're running setuid.

Comment: I like that you cite your reference.

Answer (score 1):

From the `perlvar` man page:

> $<   The real uid of this process.

So, the `$<` returns the user's real, numerical ID.  This is not the user's username, but a sysadmin-assigned number.  For example, if your username were a `aglassman` and mine, `thb`, on the same system, then your UID might be 1005 and mine, 1006, depending on which of our accounts the sysadmin had created first.  On a Linux platform, see the file `/etc/passwd` for your system's UIDs.